# how to pass valuse to non activity class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

i want to pass tow values from activity to AsyncTask class and send them from Background process to SOAP web service , but it return my null or wrong , i'm sure there is something wrnog in passing value from LoginActivity to AsyncTask .

here is my LoginActivity code :

```
        final EditText LoginId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IDLogin);
    final EditText LoginPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginPass);
    contextOfApplication = getApplicationContext();
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    boolean rememberMe = mPrefs.getBoolean("rememberMe", false);

    final String login1 = LoginId.getText().toString();
    final String pass1 = LoginPass.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
    prefs.edit().putString("login1", login1).commit();
    prefs.edit().putString("password1", pass1).commit();
```

here is calling and passing activity context to AsyncTask Constractor :

```
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    LoginActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("جاري تسجيل الدخول الرجاء الانتظار");
            progressDialog.show();

            AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller MyTask = new AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller(
                    LoginActivity.this, progressDialog,
                    getApplicationContext());
            MyTask.execute();

        }
    });
```

my FULL AsyncTask code :

```
 public class AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

Activity mActivity;
Context context;


 LoginActivity MyClass = new LoginActivity();
 public static Context contextOfApplication;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

 Context applicationContext = LoginActivity.getContextOfApplication();

// Constractor
public AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller(Activity activity,
        ProgressDialog progressDialog, Context context) {
    super();
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.context = context;
}

// BackGround Process
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    // this is executed in a background thread.
    // the result is returned to the UI thread via onPostExecute

    try {
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.sams.com";
        final String URL = "http://88.198.82.92:8080/sams1/services/LoginActvityWs?WSDL"; // usint
                                                                                            // //
                                                                                            // localhost
        final String METHOD_NAME = "login";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.sams.com/login";
        final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        final HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                URL);




        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
        String user = prefs.getString("login1", null);
        String pass = prefs.getString("password2", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

to pass values to AsyncTask subclass you either :

1- pass them throw a constructor :

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    MyObject myObject = null;
    public MyTask(MyObject myObject){
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }
//....
```

2- pass it in the execute() method parameters :

```
// your code on the Main thread which will call the execute() method
// ....
new MyTask().execute(myObject);    // i dont remember the exact name of this method, any way
```

and snippets from your AsyncTask subClass will be

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,MyObject,Void>{

@Override
public void doInBackGround(MyObject...params){
    MyObject myObject = params[0];
    // the rest of your code
}
```

just put in mind that if you want to do or edit any thing that is running on the UI thread, you
cant do it in the "doInBackground()" method, either on the preExecute() or the postExecute(), or
run it in a Runnable object (inside the doInBackground() method) but by calling runOnUI(myRunnable);

hope this helps, and just i cant remember the methods name for now, just CTRL + SPACE will help on your IDE :D

Answer (score 0):

you are already doing it in your constructor

```
AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller MyTask = new AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller(
                LoginActivity.this, progressDialog,
                getApplicationContext());
```

thats passing values there

also you are passing the context twice `LoginActivity.this` gives you `context` and `activity` so you do not need to use `getApplicationContext()`. Its recommended that you never use getApplicationContext() really

**Edit:**

if you want context all you have to do is

```
public AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller(Context context,ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    super();
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    this.context = context;
}
```

you do not need the activity

to use shared preferences all you need to do is

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: i try to use >> SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity); but still have the same problem .

Comment: what are you trying to do and what exactly is null? plus its failing because you are giving it an activity and not context. I updated my answer

Comment: i have made new try with context but still same problem , i wanna to get UserName and pass Values from LoginActivity to ==> AsyncTask DoInBackGround Method , i want to use these two values in this method to work with SOAP web service and getting the result , it's getting result 0 but the ture result should be 1 not 0 . i Think there is problem in setting or getting shared Prefrencess

Comment: so send them in your constructor

Comment: yes i know i have made this but still have same problem , ::>   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   String user = prefs.getString("login1", "1111");
   String pass = prefs.getString("password1", "2222");

Comment: if the shared preferences are returning null or the default value then they did not get saved properly to shared preferences

Comment: well did you check to see if there are actually values going into sharedpreferences? what is wrong with just sending the values in the constructor like I said?